# IIS 7 virtual directory not targeting website root?

Tags: html, css, iis-7, virtual-directory

I'm trying to configure a virtual directory in IIS 7 to target the root of a website on our server. The structure for example is as follows:

```
Websites:
    |
    --- AssetsServer
    |    - /images/
    |    - /css/
    |    - etc.
    |
    --- demoserver
         - assets (this is my virtual directory pointing to "AssetsServer")
```

Now in the demoserver's html, I have the following code for an image that I want to target the images folder within "AssetsServer":

```
<img src="/assets/images/logos/my-logo.png" alt="My Logo">
```

The URL when viewed in the browser displays as:

```
http://www.mysite.com/assets/images/logos/my-logo.png
```

This looks like it should be targeting the virtual directory, which then goes into "AssetsServer"s image folder > logos > my-logo.png. However I get a 500 error and I suspect a configuration setting is wrong (maybe not wrong but not set how I need it). When I modify the virtual directory so that it points to "AssetsServer\images\" and modify the HTML code accordingly, the image displays fine.

The reason why I want the virtual directory to target the root of "AssetsServer" is so I can call the stylesheets or images without having to create multiple virtual directories to target the individual css or images folders.

I am new to ASP and if this question has been answered already, I do apologize. I've tried my best to search and my inexperience with the terms might be hindering the process.

Thank you.

Comment: What's the exact 500 error you're getting?, if you don't see nothing else, then try accessing the web site as localhost.

Comment: @Rafael I'm seeing "500 - Internal server error. There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed." when trying to view the image directly.

Comment: IIS, also gives sub errors, for example 500.19, if you don't see it, try accessing the site in the server as localhost.

Comment: Ah yes, I am indeed receiving a 500.19 error. Is there anything specific i should be looking for in this error?

Comment: You can start here: http://blogs.iis.net/webtopics/archive/2010/03/08/troubleshooting-http-500-19-errors-in-iis-7.aspx, if this doesn't help, please share the full error (and screenshot will do it).

Comment: Bingo, the error was being thrown from a duplicate entry in the web.config files. Thank you very much @Rafael!

Comment: I have moved the comments to a full answer, please mark it as the accepted answer so it can be easily found by future users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To troubleshot 500 errors on IIS, you need to get the substatus (for example 500.19), then check the error code, in the case of 500.19 errors (the more common), you can start here: http://blogs.iis.net/webtopics/archive/2010/03/08/troubleshooting-http-500-19-errors-in-iis-7.aspx.

If you're not getting the substatus and/or error code, then you should access the site in the server using localhost.